# array change detection property in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I  have  an component in which  i am showing values fetched from  database. there is also  Add button.  on click of Add ,  i  am pushing text field value to  array. same is  binded to  component.  The value is getting set in  array. [(ngModel)]   but  not displaying in  text box.  only displaying when  i click  inside box.  i  not able  to  identify  cause  for this  behaviour. plz help

```js
onAdd() {
  if (this.emailRecipients.length === 0) {
    this.emailRecipients = [];
  }
  this.emailRecipients.push(this.enterEmailAddress);
         
}
```

```html
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Angular Change Detection, and is an expected behavior.

Instead of modifying the array by calling `.push`, you should be creating a new array instance for the changes to be reflected.

```ts
    this.emailRecipients = [...this.emailRecipients, this.enterEmailAddress];
```

From PrimeNG docs:

> Change Detection of Suggestions
> AutoComplete uses setter based checking to realize if the suggestions has changed to update the UI. In order this to work, your changes such as adding or removing a record should always create a new array reference instead of manipulating an existing array as Angular does not trigger setters if the reference does not change.
>
> Note that if no suggestions are available after searching, provide an empty array instead of a null value.

Reference: [AutoComplete](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

write it like this,

```
onAdd() {
  if (this.emailRecipients.length === 0) {
    this.emailRecipients = [];
  }
  this.emailRecipients.push(this.enterEmailAddress);
  this.emailRecipients = [...this.emailRecipients];
         
}
```